# Deleting Test-licenses from Office365

Tags: 2013, office-365, csom, provider-hosted-app, licensing

I have written a method that installs a test-license to my O365-SharePoint. It uses the following method:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.ImportAppLicense()
```

This works fine, but now I have the following problem:
1. I used a (randomly generated) productId each time that does not match to my app (and which I do not know anymore)
2. After a few successful tests I receive the following error:

```
The number of test licenses has exceeded the allowed quota that can be imported, which is 10.
```

As this error message is quite clear: How do I solve this issue? **How can I delete my already generated Test-Licenses?**

Comment: have you tried to login on the site and try to delete from there manully

Comment: I would love too, but I cannot find them. That's part of the problem. :) They do not appear under "Add an App/Manage Licenses"